# How to solve Critical Logical Driver Error

Tags: raid, redhat, logging

I was checking the logs in server when i came across this message.

```
Nov 4 12:52:05 SERVERNAME ServeRAID Manager Agent:[338] Periodic scan found one 
  or more critical logical drives: controller 1. Repair as soon as possible to 
  avoid data loss.
```

1. What does this mean?
2. Is it Critical or can be ignored?
3. If critical how to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

1. This means that you probably have a disk in a failed or failing state in your array.
2. It says its critical, so I'd assume you should pay attention to it.
3. You can solve it by determining what is causing the array to be critical. It's probably a failed disk. Replace it.